# Derived class - extending properties

Tags: c#, derived-class

i am still learning and fighting derived classes.

tried something simple ( from the examples i have seen all over ):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Title {get;set;}
}

public class Channel : BaseClass
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}


Channel myChannel = new Channel();
myChannel.Title = "hello";
myChannel.Path = "123";
```

but i get an error on the `myChannel.Path` line saying `BaseClass does not contain a definition for Path and no extension....`

help me please, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show your real code. The error message doesn't match the code you have shown. The code you have shown is just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example you show is fine. I think in your actual code you have:

```
BaseClass myChannel = new Channel();
myChannel.Title = "hello";
myChannel.Path = "123";
```

so the answer is simply: ensure your local variable is typed as `Channel`, since it is the the *expression type* (typically: the type of a variable) that determines the starting point for member resolution.

As a terse alternative in C# 3:

```
var myChannel = new Channel { Title = "hello", Path = "123" };
```

Comment: i think i have actually used `var myChannel = new Channel();` and then set the properties. might that be the problem?

Comment: @Dementic no; at some point you must be assigning-this-to a `BaseClass` variable, or returning it typed *as* `BaseClass`. Can you post the *actual* code that reproduces this scenario (and just the code necessary for this; not everything) - as your sample shown **does not**.

Comment: i will do so later on ( its on the home computer ).

Answer (score 5):

The code you've given compiles fine. I suspect you've *actually* got code like this:

```
BaseClass myChannel = new Channel();
myChannel.Title = "hello";
myChannel.Path = "123";
```

Note that here, the compile-time type of `myChannel` is `BaseClass` - so the compiler wouldn't be able to find the `Path` property, as it's not present in `BaseClass`. The compiler can only find members based on the *compile-time* type of the variable. (Leaving dynamic typing aside...)

If you stick to the code you actually posted, i.e. with a compile-time type of `Channel`, then all should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code as written runs fine. What I suspect you have is

```
BaseClass myChannel = new Channel()
```

If so,  the problem is that myChannel is a reference to a BaseClass and cannot see the Path property.

If you need to access Path you can do so with

```
(myChannel as Channel).Path = "123";
```

hth, 
Alan.

Comment: Re the `as` - unless you are going to handle the `null` case, it would be better to use `((Channel)myChannel).Path = ...`, as that will give a more appropriate error message.